# Glob triple stars ***

Tags: gulp

I am working with gulp and one example was using the following code

```
var jsWatchFiles = [
    paths.assets + 'js/***.js',
    paths.assets + 'lib/***.js',
    paths.wwwroot + 'lib/***.js',
    './gulpfile.js'
];
```

Are those triple stars just a shorthand for

```
paths.assets + 'js/**/*.js'
```

Or does it have a difference meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Triple wildcard has no meaning at all, it might be a typo or a custom pattern for some functions.

Check this link that references the glob patterns:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Glob-0.7.4/docs/System-FilePath-Glob.html